# how to fix Multiple requests in the process state with the same ASP.NET Session ID

Tags: caching, iis, crash, w3wp, diagnostic-tools

ı have a site that site cause to crash of ISS .When I investigate this problem using diagnostic tool, I saw this description in report.How can I resolve this problem?

Analysis Summary
    Error
    Description 
            In w3w_site __PID__5568__Date__05_03_2017__Time_10_12_55AM__406__First Chance Stack Overflow.dmp the assembly instruction at ntdll!_alloca_probe+27 in C:\Windows\System32\ntdll.dll from Microsoft Corporation has caused a stack overflow exception (0xC00000FD) when trying to read from memory location 0x1f252000 on thread 57
          Multiple requests in the process state with the same ASP.NET Session ID were detected in the dump file. At any point of time, ASP.NET executes only one request with the same session id and the remaining requests are queued behind the request which is getting executed
     Recommendation
            Please check why you got more than one request for the same ASP.NET Session ID by viewing the HTTP report and the ASP.NET Session ID Report

```
Thread 57 - System ID 5984
    .NET Call Stack

    System_Data_ni!DomainNeutralILStubClass.IL_STUB_PInvoke(SNI_ConnWrapper*, SNI_Packet*)+41
    [[InlinedCallFrame]]
    System_Data_ni!SNINativeMethodWrapper.SNIWritePacket(System.Runtime.InteropServices.SafeHandle, System.Runtime.InteropServices.SafeHandle, Boolean)+81
    [[InlinedCallFrame]]
    System_Data_ni!System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.SNIWritePacket(System.Data.SqlClient.SNIHandle, System.Data.SqlClient.SNIPacket, UInt32 ByRef, Boolean, Boolean)+ba
    System_Data_ni!System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.WriteSni(Boolean)+5c
    System_Data_ni!System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.WritePacket(Byte, Boolean)+152
    System_Data_ni!System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TdsLogin(System.Data.SqlClient.SqlLogin, FeatureExtension, System.Data.SqlClient.SessionData)+83e
    System_Data_ni!System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.Login(System.Data.SqlClient.ServerInfo, System.Data.ProviderBase.TimeoutTimer, System.String, System.Security.SecureString)+15c
    System_Data_ni!System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.AttemptOneLogin(System.Data.SqlClient.ServerInfo, System.String, System.Security.SecureString, Boolean, System.Data.ProviderBase.TimeoutTimer, Boolean)+ef
    System_Data_ni!System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginNoFailover(System.Data.SqlClient.ServerInfo, System.String, System.Security.SecureString, Boolean, System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionString, System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCredential, System.Data.ProviderBase.TimeoutTimer)+107
    System_Data_ni!System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OpenLoginEnlist(System.Data.ProviderBase.TimeoutTimer, System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionString, System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCredential, System.String, System.Security.SecureString, Boolean)+c9
    System_Data_ni!System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPoolIdentity, System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionString, System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCredential, System.Object, System.String, System.Security.SecureString, Boolean, System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionString, System.Data.SqlClient.SessionData)+207
    System_Data_ni!System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions, System.Data.Common.DbConnectionPoolKey, System.Object, System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool, System.Data.Common.DbConnection, System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions)+117
    System_Data_ni!System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreateNonPooledConnection(System.Data.Common.DbConnection, System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPoolGroup, System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions)+27
    System_Data_ni!System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(System.Data.Common.DbConnection, System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCompletionSource`1, System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions, System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal, System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal ByRef)+51e9b3
    System_Data_ni!System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(System.Data.Common.DbConnection, System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory, System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCompletionSource`1, System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions)+74
    System_Data_ni!System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(System.Data.Common.DbConnection, System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory, System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCompletionSource`1, System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions)+11
    System_Data_ni!System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCompletionSource`1)+5f
    System_Data_ni!System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCompletionSource`1)+6f
    System_Data_ni!System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()+61
    System_Data_ni!System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.FillInternal(System.Data.DataSet, System.Data.DataTable[], Int32, Int32, System.String, System.Data.IDbCommand, System.Data.CommandBehavior)+7a
    System_Data_ni!System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(System.Data.DataTable[], Int32, Int32, System.Data.IDbCommand, System.Data.CommandBehavior)+a1
    System_Data_ni!System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(System.Data.DataTable)+6d
    FinansinvestCMS.ContentMaker.ContentHelper.GetContentList(System.String, System.String, Int32, Boolean, ContentType, Boolean)+2f8
    FinansinvestCMS.ContentMaker.ContentHelper.GetContent(System.String, System.String, Int32, Boolean, ContentType)+4b
    FinansinvestCMS.ContentMaker.ContentHelper.GetContent(System.String, Int32, Boolean)+3a
    FinansinvestV2.Main.Core.Operations.CMSOperations.GetJsonObject[[System.__Canon, mscorlib]](System.String)+28
    FinansinvestV2.Main.Core.Operations.CMSOperations.GetSiteNavigation()+22
    FinansinvestV2.Main.Core.Utilities.StaticContent+<>c.<.cctor>b__2_0()+6
    CommonLibrary.Caching.CachedObjectBase`1[[System.__Canon, mscorlib]].InvokeSupplierFunction()+35
    CommonLibrary.Caching.CachedObjectBase`1[[System.__Canon, mscorlib]].InternalRefresh()+a0
    CommonLibrary.Caching.AspNetCacheProvider+<>c__DisplayClass4_0`1[[System.__Canon, mscorlib]].b__0(System.String, System.Object, System.Web.Caching.CacheItemRemovedReason)+b8
    System_Web_ni!System.Web.Caching.CacheEntry.CallCacheItemRemovedCallback(System.Web.Caching.CacheItemRemovedCallback, System.Web.Caching.CacheItemRemovedReason)+910dcf
    System_Web_ni!System.Web.Caching.CacheEntry.Close(System.Web.Caching.CacheItemRemovedReason)+1c6
    System_Web_ni!System.Web.Caching.CacheSingle.UpdateCache(System.Web.Caching.CacheKey, System.Web.Caching.CacheEntry, Boolean, System.Web.Caching.CacheItemRemovedReason, System.Object ByRef)+88b
    System_Web_ni!System.Web.Caching.CacheMultiple.UpdateCache(System.Web.Caching.CacheKey, System.Web.Caching.CacheEntry, Boolean, System.Web.Caching.CacheItemRemovedReason, System.Object ByRef)+37
    System_Web_ni!System.Web.Caching.CacheInternal.DoInsert(Boolean, System.String, System.Object, System.Web.Caching.CacheDependency, System.DateTime, System.TimeSpan, System.Web.Caching.CacheItemPriority, System.Web.Caching.CacheItemRemovedCallback, Boolean)+74
    System_Web_ni!System.Web.Caching.Cache.Insert(System.String, System.Object, System.Web.Caching.CacheDependency, System.DateTime, System.TimeSpan, System.Web.Caching.CacheItemPriority, System.Web.Caching.CacheItemRemovedCallback)+52
    CommonLibrary.Caching.AspNetCacheProvider.Set[[System.__Canon, mscorlib]](System.String, System.__Canon, System.TimeSpan, System.Action)+1f2
    CommonLibrary.Caching.CachedObjectBase`1[[System.__Canon, mscorlib]].InternalRefresh()+19e
    CommonLibrary.Caching.AspNetCacheProvider+<>c__DisplayClass4_0`1[[System.__Canon, mscorlib]].b__0(System.String, System.Object, System.Web.Caching.CacheItemRemovedReason)+b8
    System_Web_ni!System.Web.Caching.CacheEntry.CallCacheItemRemovedCallback(System.Web.Caching.CacheItemRemovedCallback, System.Web.Caching.CacheItemRemovedReason)+910dcf
    System_Web_ni!System.Web.Caching.CacheEntry.Close(System.Web.Caching.CacheItemRemovedReason)+1c6
    System_Web_ni!System.Web.Caching.CacheSingle.UpdateCache(System.Web.Caching.CacheKey, System.Web.Caching.CacheEntry, Boolean, System.Web.Caching.CacheItemRemovedReason, System.Object ByRef)+88b
    System_Web_ni!System.Web.Caching.CacheMultiple.UpdateCache(System.Web.Caching.CacheKey, System.Web.Caching.CacheEntry, Boolean, System.Web.Caching.CacheItemRemovedReason, System.Object ByRef)+37
    System_Web_ni!System.Web.Caching.CacheInternal.DoInsert(Boolean, System.String, System.Object, System.Web.Caching.CacheDependency, System.DateTime, System.TimeSpan, System.Web.Caching.CacheItemPriority, System.Web.Caching.CacheItemRemovedCallback, Boolean)+74
    System_Web_ni!System.Web.Caching.Cache.Insert(System.String, System.Object, System.Web.Caching.CacheDependency, System.DateTime, System.TimeSpan, System.Web.Caching.CacheItemPriority, System.Web.Caching.CacheItemRemovedCallback)+52
    CommonLibrary.Caching.AspNetCacheProvider.Set[[System.__Canon, mscorlib]](System.String, System.__Canon, System.TimeSpan, System.Action)+1f2
    CommonLibrary.Caching.CachedObjectBase`1[[System.__Canon, mscorlib]].InternalRefresh()+19e
    CommonLibrary.Caching.AspNetCacheProvider+<>c__DisplayClass4_0`1[[System.__Canon, mscorlib]].b__0(System.String, System.Object, System.Web.Caching.CacheItemRemovedReason)+b8
    System_Web_ni!System.Web.Caching.CacheEntry.CallCacheItemRemovedCallback(System.Web.Caching.CacheItemRemovedCallback, System.Web.Caching.CacheItemRemovedReason)+910dcf
    System_Web_ni!System.Web.Caching.CacheEntry.Close(System.Web.Caching.CacheItemRemovedReason)+1c6
    System_Web_ni!System.Web.Caching.CacheSingle.UpdateCache(System.Web.Caching.CacheKey, System.Web.Caching.CacheEntry, Boolean, System.Web.Caching.CacheItemRemovedReason, System.Object ByRef)+88b
    System_Web_ni!System.Web.Caching.CacheMultiple.UpdateCache(System.Web.Caching.CacheKey, System.Web.Caching.CacheEntry, Boolean, System.Web.Caching.CacheItemRemovedReason, System.Object ByRef)+37
    System_Web_ni!System.Web.Caching.CacheInternal.DoInsert(Boolean, System.String, System.Object, System.Web.Caching.CacheDependency, System.DateTime, System.TimeSpan, System.Web.Caching.CacheItemPriority, System.Web.Caching.CacheItemRemovedCallback, Boolean)+74
    System_Web_ni!System.Web.Caching.Cache.Insert(System.String, System.Object, System.Web.Caching.CacheDependency, System.DateTime, System.TimeSpan, System.Web.Caching.CacheItemPriority, System.Web.Caching.CacheItemRemovedCallback)+52
    CommonLibrary.Caching.AspNetCacheProvider.Set[[System.__Canon, mscorlib]](System.String, System.__Canon, System.TimeSpan, System.Action)+1f2
    CommonLibrary.Caching.CachedObjectBase`1[[System.__Canon, mscorlib]].InternalRefresh()+19e
    CommonLibrary.Caching.AspNetCacheProvider+<>c__DisplayClass4_0`1[[System.__Canon, mscorlib]].b__0(System.String, System.Object, System.Web.Caching.CacheItemRemovedReason)+b8
    System_Web_ni!System.Web.Caching.CacheEntry.CallCacheItemRemovedCallback(System.Web.Caching.CacheItemRemovedCallback, System.Web.Caching.CacheItemRemovedReason)+910dcf
    System_Web_ni!System.Web.Caching.CacheEntry.Close(System.Web.Caching.CacheItemRemovedReason)+1c6
    System_Web_ni!System.Web.Caching.CacheSingle.UpdateCache(System.Web.Caching.CacheKey, System.Web.Caching.CacheEntry, Boolean, System.Web.Caching.CacheItemRemovedReason, System.Object ByRef)+88b


    System_Web_ni!System.Web.Caching.CacheEntry.Close(System.Web.Caching.CacheItemRemovedReason)+1c6
    System_Web_ni!System.Web.Caching.CacheSingle.UpdateCache(System.Web.Caching.CacheKey, System.Web.Caching.CacheEntry, Boolean, System.Web.Caching.CacheItemRemovedReason, System.Object ByRef)+88b
    System_Web_ni!System.Web.Caching.CacheMultiple.UpdateCache(System.Web.Caching.CacheKey, System.Web.Caching.CacheEntry, Boolean, System.Web.Caching.CacheItemRemovedReason, System.Object ByRef)+37
    System_Web_ni!System.Web.Caching.CacheInternal.DoInsert(Boolean, System.String, System.Object, System.Web.Caching.CacheDependency, System.DateTime, System.TimeSpan, System.Web.Caching.CacheItemPriority, System.Web.Caching.CacheItemRemovedCallback, Boolean)+74
    System_Web_ni!System.Web.Caching.Cache.Insert(System.String, System.Object, System.Web.Caching.CacheDependency, System.DateTime, System.TimeSpan, System.Web.Caching.CacheItemPriority, System.Web.Caching.CacheItemRemovedCallback)+52
    CommonLibrary.Caching.AspNetCacheProvider.Set[[System.__Canon, mscorlib]](System.String, System.__Canon, System.TimeSpan, System.Action)+1f2
    CommonLibrary.Caching.CachedObjectBase`1[[System.__Canon, mscorlib]].InternalRefresh()+19e
    CommonLibrary.Caching.AspNetCacheProvider+<>c__DisplayClass4_0`1[[System.__Canon, mscorlib]].b__0(System.String, System.Object, System.Web.Caching.CacheItemRemovedReason)+b8
    System_Web_ni!System.Web.Caching.CacheEntry.CallCacheItemRemovedCallback(System.Web.Caching.CacheItemRemovedCallback, System.Web.Caching.CacheItemRemovedReason)+910dcf
    System_Web_ni!System.Web.Caching.CacheEntry.Close(System.Web.Caching.CacheItemRemovedReason)+1c6
    System_Web_ni!System.Web.Caching.CacheSingle.UpdateCache(System.Web.Caching.CacheKey, System.Web.Caching.CacheEntry, Boolean, System.Web.Caching.CacheItemRemovedReason, System.Object ByRef)+88b
    System_Web_ni!System.Web.Caching.CacheMultiple.UpdateCache(System.Web.Caching.CacheKey, System.Web.Caching.CacheEntry, Boolean, System.Web.Caching.CacheItemRemovedReason, System.Object ByRef)+37
    System_Web_ni!System.Web.Caching.CacheInternal.DoInsert(Boolean, System.String, System.Object, System.Web.Caching.CacheDependency, System.DateTime, System.TimeSpan, System.Web.Caching.CacheItemPriority, System.Web.Caching.CacheItemRemovedCallback, Boolean)+74
    System_Web_ni!System.Web.Caching.Cache.Insert(System.String, System.Object, System.Web.Caching.CacheDependency, System.DateTime, System.TimeSpan, System.Web.Caching.CacheItemPriority, System.Web.Caching.CacheItemRemovedCallback)+52
    CommonLibrary.Caching.AspNetCacheProvider.Set[[System.__Canon, mscorlib]](System.String, System.__Canon, System.TimeSpan, System.Action)+1f2
    CommonLibrary.Caching.CachedObjectBase`1[[System.__Canon, mscorlib]].InternalRefresh()+19e
    CommonLibrary.Caching.CachedObjectBase`1[[System.__Canon, mscorlib]].get_Value()+183
    FinansinvestV2.Base.FinansInvestWebViewPage`1[[System.__Canon, mscorlib]].InitHelpers()+1eb
    System.Web.Mvc.RazorView.RenderView(System.Web.Mvc.ViewContext, System.IO.TextWriter, System.Object)+6e
    System.Web.Mvc.BuildManagerCompiledView.Render(System.Web.Mvc.ViewContext, System.IO.TextWriter)+6c
    System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(System.Web.Mvc.ControllerContext)+125
    System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResult(System.Web.Mvc.ControllerContext, System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult)+e
    System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(System.Collections.Generic.IList`1, Int32, System.Web.Mvc.ResultExecutingContext, System.Web.Mvc.ControllerContext, System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult)+39
    System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(System.Collections.Generic.IList`1, Int32, System.Web.Mvc.ResultExecutingContext, System.Web.Mvc.ControllerContext, System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult)+120
    System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(System.Collections.Generic.IList`1, Int32, System.Web.Mvc.ResultExecutingContext, System.Web.Mvc.ControllerContext, System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult)+120
    System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultWithFilters(System.Web.Mvc.ControllerContext, System.Collections.Generic.IList`1, System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult)+35
    System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker+<>c__DisplayClass21+<>c__DisplayClass2b.b__1c()+ae
    System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker+<>c__DisplayClass21.b__1e(System.IAsyncResult)+25
    System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper+WrappedAsyncResult`1[[System.Boolean, mscorlib]].CallEndDelegate(System.IAsyncResult)+b
    System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper+WrappedAsyncResultBase`1[[System.Boolean, mscorlib]].End()+32
    System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(System.IAsyncResult)+2d
    System.Web.Mvc.Controller.b__1d(System.IAsyncResult, ExecuteCoreState)+e
    System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper+WrappedAsyncVoid`1[[System.Web.Mvc.Controller+ExecuteCoreState, System.Web.Mvc]].CallEndDelegate(System.IAsyncResult)+25
    System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper+WrappedAsyncResultBase`1[[System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncVoid, System.Web.Mvc]].End()+37
    System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(System.IAsyncResult)+2a
    System.Web.Mvc.Controller.b__15(System.IAsyncResult, System.Web.Mvc.Controller)+d
    System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper+WrappedAsyncVoid`1[[System.__Canon, mscorlib]].CallEndDelegate(System.IAsyncResult)+1d
    System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper+WrappedAsyncResultBase`1[[System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncVoid, System.Web.Mvc]].End()+37
    System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(System.IAsyncResult)+20
    System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(System.IAsyncResult)+b
    System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.b__5(System.IAsyncResult, ProcessRequestState)+16
    System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper+WrappedAsyncVoid`1[[System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler+ProcessRequestState, System.Web.Mvc]].CallEndDelegate(System.IAsyncResult)+25
    System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper+WrappedAsyncResultBase`1[[System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncVoid, System.Web.Mvc]].End()+37
    System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(System.IAsyncResult)+20
    System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(System.IAsyncResult)+a
    System_Web_ni!System.Web.HttpApplication+CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()+912fb1
    System_Web_ni!System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep, Boolean ByRef)+9c
    System_Web_ni!System.Web.HttpApplication+PipelineStepManager.ResumeSteps(System.Exception)+43d
    System_Web_ni!System.Web.HttpApplication.BeginProcessRequestNotification(System.Web.HttpContext, System.AsyncCallback)+60
    System_Web_ni!System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(System.Web.Hosting.IIS7WorkerRequest, System.Web.HttpContext)+bb
    System_Web_ni!System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationHelper(IntPtr, IntPtr, IntPtr, Int32)+2d7
    [[InlinedCallFrame]]
    System_Web_ni!System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotification(IntPtr, IntPtr, IntPtr, Int32)+1f
    System_Web_ni!DomainNeutralILStubClass.IL_STUB_PInvoke(IntPtr, System.Web.RequestNotificationStatus ByRef)+3d
    [[InlinedCallFrame]]
    System_Web_ni!System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationHelper(IntPtr, IntPtr, IntPtr, Int32)+456
    [[InlinedCallFrame]]
    System_Web_ni!System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotification(IntPtr, IntPtr, IntPtr, Int32)+1f
    [[ContextTransitionFrame]]
```

Comment: Let me know if you're still looking for an answer on this one !

Comment: I solved the problem ty

Comment: @AhmetÇolak what was the problem/solution?

Comment: @Rafe  the cache remains in the loop at the code . c# caching is filling up the machine's RAM when caching.I change the this mechanism.